# how to get the saved records from another table

Tags: php, laravel

So I have a crud application with a Registration table and an ExtraRegistration table.

In the Registration table, I got a foreach with selects with options from the ExtraOptions table.

**What I have right now:** In the RegistrationController I make a new ExtraRegistration and also save the select options to the ExtraRegistration table.
Now when i click on edit, on one of the registrations, there is no information i just filled in.

**What I want:**
I want it so when you create a new Registration, The select save to the ExtraRegistration table, but then when you want to edit the record in de Registration table in the application, the select is empty because I saved it in the ExtraRegistrations.

So my question is how I get the select(and the other inputs) from the ExtraRegistration table so that it shows the select in the edit form in the "**Registrations**".

**RegistrationController**

```
options = Extra::where("exa_form_id", $afstand->asd_form_id)->get();
foreach($options as $option){
  $input_name = "option_" . $option->exa_id;
  $input_option = $request->$input_name;
  if(!is_null($input_option)){
    $input_name_extra = "extraoptions_" . $option->exa_id;
    $input_option_extra = $request->$input_name_extra;
    $extraregistration = new ExtraRegistration();
    $extraregistration->iea_registration_id = $registration->isg_id;
    $extraregistration->iea_extra_id = $input_option;
    $extraregistration->iea_extraoption_id = $input_option_extra;
    $extraregistration->iea_price = $option->exa_price;
    $extraregistration->save();
  }
}
```

I hope I explained it well enough! Thanks in advance

Comment: so what is the relation between the 2 models ? i guess u may miss that .

Comment: Hi, the ExtraRegistration has a registration_id, and the Registration has an extra_id.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I got it right, you save the, let's say checkbox options, for `Extra` model, to another model called `ExtraRegistration`, and you want to show those options when you're editing `Extra` model, right?

In order to do that, your models should be related. If you don't have it already, add `extra_id` to your `ExtraRegistration` table and create a belongsTo relation on your `ExtraRegistration` model.

```
public function extra(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Extra');
}
```

Now your models are related, and you can list the options for model `Extra` like this:

```
$extra = Extra::find($id)->first(); 
$options = ExtraRegistration::where('extra_id', $extra->id)->get()
```

Hope that I got your question right. If you have any additional question, feel free to ask.

Comment: Hello, the model from the Registration goes to the ExtraRegistration, and then back to the Registration again to show it when you click edit. I do have an registration_id in the ExtraRegistration table.

Comment: So the process is basically the same, just switch the where condition to your foreign key name.